# Multiply data frame with weights from another data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with expression values, and I have weights in data frame `Weights`. 
For each column in `df` I would like to multiply each row in `df` with the corresponding row in `Weights` that has similar row-name.

Then for each column in `df` you get weighted values of the rows.

Please see my exampke output.

df

```
Gene              MMRF_1021    MMRF_1024   MMRF_1029   MMRF_1030    MMRF_1031
ENSG00000007062   0.05374547   0.01258559   0.0000000   1.2985088   0.37618693
ENSG00000012124   0.13436368   0.27688288   0.2780448   0.7158432   0.03271195
```

Weights

```
   Gene                   Pre.BI       Pre.BII       Immature     Naive         Memory       Plasmacell
   ENSG00000007062        0.006368928  0.000000e+00  0.000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
   ENSG00000012124        0.000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000000 -0.009728154
```

out:

```
 Sample    Gene            Pre.BI            Pre.BI   Immature     Naive         Memory       Plasmacell
 MMRF_1021 ENSG00000007062 0.000342301       0        0            0             0             0
 MMRF_1021 ENSG00000012124 0                 0        0            0             0            -0.001307111
 MMRF_1024 ENSG00000007062 8.015672e-05      0        0            0             0             0
 MMRF_1024 ENSG00000012124 0                 0        0            0             0            -0.002693559
 .....
```

dput df:

```
structure(list(MMRF_1021 = c(0.0537454710193116, 0.134363677548279
), MMRF_1024 = c(0.0125855939107651, 0.276882875966623), MMRF_1029 = c(0, 
0.278044754955015), MMRF_1030 = c(1.29850876031527, 0.715843203834688
), MMRF_1031 = c(0.37618693249153, 0.032711952160723)), row.names = c("ENSG00000007062", 
"ENSG00000012124"), class = "data.frame")
```

dput weights:

```
structure(list(Pre.BI = c(0.006368928, 0), Pre.BII = c(0, 0), 
    Immature = c(0, 0), Naive = c(0, 0), Memory = c(0, 0), Plasmacell = c(0, 
    -0.009728154)), row.names = c("ENSG00000007062", "ENSG00000012124"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example using `dput()`?

Comment: added dput for df and weights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
library(tidyverse)

joinedDataframe <- df %>%
    rownames_to_column("gene") %>%
    gather("sample", "value", -gene) %>%
    left_join(weights %>%
                  rownames_to_column("gene")
              , by = "gene")

joinedDataframe %>%
    mutate(Pre.BI = Pre.BI * value
           , Pre.BII = Pre.BII * value
           , Immature = Immature * value
           , Naive = Naive * value
           , Memory = Memory * value
           , Plasmacell = Plasmacell * value) %>%
    select(-value)

              gene    sample       Pre.BI Pre.BII Immature Naive Memory    Plasmacell
1  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1021 3.423010e-04       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
2  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1021 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0013071105
3  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1024 8.015674e-05       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
4  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1024 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0026935593
5  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1029 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
6  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1029 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0027048622
7  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1030 8.270109e-03       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
8  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1030 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0069638329
9  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1031 2.395907e-03       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
10 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1031 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0003182269
```

Comment: I totally recommend that, yes. Here's a freely available online book, that is written very well: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: Actually, it is not what I wanted. You only have the column "value" but I want a new value for each column in "weight". Please see my output.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you see that I updated my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your expected result, I think the following is what you are after. For example, `Plasmacell` for `MMRF_1024 ENSG00000012124` is -0.002693559 (0.27688288 * -0.009728154). In order to get this number, I converted both data frames to long-format data. Then, I joined them. By this time you have two columns to handle multiplication (i.e., gene_value and value). After this, I converted the data to a wide-format data frame.

```
librrary(tidyverse)

rownames_to_column(df) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -rowname, names_to = "gene", values_to = "gene_value") -> temp1

rownames_to_column(weights) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -rowname, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") -> temp2

left_join(temp1, temp2, by = "rowname") %>% 
mutate(answer = gene_value * value) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = rowname:gene, names_from = "variable", values_from = "answer")

   rowname         gene         Pre.BI Pre.BII Immature Naive Memory Plasmacell
   <chr>           <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1021 0.000342        0        0     0      0   0       
 2 ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1024 0.0000802       0        0     0      0   0       
 3 ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1029 0               0        0     0      0   0       
 4 ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1030 0.00827         0        0     0      0   0       
 5 ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1031 0.00240         0        0     0      0   0       
 6 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1021 0               0        0     0      0  -0.00131 
 7 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1024 0               0        0     0      0  -0.00269 
 8 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1029 0               0        0     0      0  -0.00270 
 9 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1030 0               0        0     0      0  -0.00696 
10 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1031 0               0        0     0      0  -0.000318
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind,
                 c(make.row.names = F,
                   lapply(seq(ncol(df)), 
                          function(k) cbind(Gene = rownames(df[k]), 
                                            Sample = names(df[k]), 
                                            df[,k]*weights[match(rownames(weights),rownames(df)),]))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
              Gene    Sample       Pre.BI Pre.BII Immature Naive Memory    Plasmacell
1  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1021 3.423010e-04       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
2  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1021 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0013071105
3  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1024 8.015674e-05       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
4  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1024 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0026935593
5  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1029 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
6  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1029 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0027048622
7  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1030 8.270109e-03       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
8  ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1030 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0069638329
9  ENSG00000007062 MMRF_1031 2.395907e-03       0        0     0      0  0.0000000000
10 ENSG00000012124 MMRF_1031 0.000000e+00       0        0     0      0 -0.0003182269
```